# LibGDX on Netbeans - Compiles fine but Nebeans says "Package Android does not exist"

Tags: android, netbeans, gradle, libgdx, netbeans-8

I've looked near and far for an answer.

My libgdx project works great, it compiles and it runs. Android, desktop and IOS (on my mac).

But Netbeans (8.1) shows all my android imports as errors and says "Package Android does not exist" even though it compiles fine.

My project is created with the Libgdx wizard and there for uses gradle.

How do I fix this?

***Edit:***
I added a workaround! I add the following to my build.gradle file

```
dependencies {
compile files('libs/android.jar');
}
```

Reload the project and there! It finds everything!
Then I comment that line out without reloading the project and then the compile works :)

Comment: No help, but I've been trying to track this down for weeks myself. As much as I like some things about NetBeans, I've found myself using IDEA more and more over the past years. FWIW, it works fine with gradle libgdx configs. I'll probably keep trying to get it working for a bit, but unless Android support in NB gets active support & docs (preferably from someone on the NB team), I'm going to have to give up on it. If I do figure anything out, I'll be sure to post.

Answer (score 0):

i'm using netbeans for java, and was seeing the same error

for me, after disabling the maven plugin, shutting down, deleting the cache, and restarting, an error dialog popped up saying junit 3.8.2 had been removed and offering to automatically "fix" it. and that resolved the issue

this has the downside that i wont be able to open older versions in netbeans (without jumping thru these hoops every time), making bisects prohibitive